# MySQL - null values for datetime column returned as unix epoch in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

There is a `datetime` column called `paymentdate`in my `purchases` table that I wish to keep as `NULL` until the user pays.

That way I can do an `isset`check to see if it has been made non null or not and then execute the rest of code accordingly.

However, even though a `paymentdate` value in MySQL for newly entered rows is clearly shown as `NULL` when seen in MySQL Workbench, whenever I `dd` the same row in my Laravel application, it shows the `paymentdate` value as the unix epoch. 
I want it to be shown as `NULL` or at least pass the checks for null.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent? If so, do you have the $dates property on the corresponding model including this column?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eloquent. Nope haven't done that. Could you please provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Laravel's Eloquent with dates you must include the name of all date columns in the `$dates` property of the corresponding model class. This feature transform dates into Carbon objects which extends PHP's DateTime class. See [Eloquent Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

In your case you would have: `protected $dates = ['paymentdate'];`